# Does soaked oats lower glycemic index (GI) and does it chemically/biologically count as cooked?

Tags: nutrition, benefits, healthy-cooking, glycemic-index

what's the best way to prepare or cook oats for the benefits?

- does soaking oats have any benefits such as lowering GI?
- does cooking oats have more benefits?
- how long do you need to microwave oats to get those benefits?
- what's the minimally viable time you should microwave your oats to get these benefits

Comment: By GI do you mean glycemic index? It's a good idea to spell out acronyms when you first use them in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: yea, im sure ppl that knows a lot about oats would know, no worries

Comment: Most people in a medical forum will read GI as meaning gastrointenstinal,not glycemic index. I fixed it for you.

Comment: would this question be better over at a more food-related or nutrition-related (don't know if they have one) se? if so someone could just move it

Comment: Cooking.SE will accept the question about them being cooked, but they won't accept health questions so the GI part of your question would be off topic there.

Comment: ..someone could just post something helpful in comments then.. the question is about how cooking affect nutrition-related, the cooking ppl don't know anything about food science or anything besides just how to cook and those stuff related, they dont know any science, is there no nutrition-related stack, it's a pretty hard qeustion

Comment: If someone had an answer they would post it. I recommend research on your own.

Comment: i already did years of research, as with all any of my questions, just delete it

Comment: You can delete it yourself if you want. I would suggest splitting the question up and asking about the soaking thing in cooking.se.